# How to run django project live

Tags: python, django, nginx, server, web-hosting

I have developed few websites with **Django**. Now i want to see them live. I have already purchase **VPS server** hosting. All are setup like `pip/applications` . Also when i am running server it show

> Django version 1.11, using settings 'wer.settings'
>
> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>
> Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

But i don't know why it's not showing in my domain.

What are the changes i need to make in `settings.py` file to show it in my domain or host it live.
Is it not possible with the same command :-

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Python server is not for production, also a web page has to be in port 80, not 8000. You should contact your service host or read the help to know what configuration is needed.

Comment: How  about nginx  server ? And if i use nginx do i need to make a lot off changes in my codes ?

Comment: Your host has the web server, nginx, apache, you should research what are your host services, and what configurations is needed.

Comment: Thanks for you reply

Comment: Usually a host service provide you with a user and an admin panel where the settings are, like the ftp for uploading the files and the access to databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gunicorn, nginx and supervisor provide a good and stable production environment. More details here; https://hackernoon.com/deploy-django-app-with-nginx-gunicorn-postgresql-supervisor-9c6d556a25ac

Note: I did not write this article, but it provides enough information to get you there.

Answer (score 1):

Runserver in django not meant for production but if you want to test in live environment use :

```
python manage.py runserver  0.0.0.0:8000
```

Use your vps server ip to browse the website

```
http://vps_server_ip:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a guide for [Setting up Django and your web server with uWSGI and nginx](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)